# how can i return array from class/function with foreach in PHP

Tags: php, function, class, pdo, foreach

Hi all im trying to implement PDO connection with classes. i want to do it like this:

```
//The Query
$ctrl  = ("SELECT * FROM table WHERE uye_ad = ?");
$query = new BerkaySimsek();
$val   = $sorgu->select($ctrl,"aa","uye_soyad");

//The Class
public function select($sorgu,$deger,$yazdirilacak)
{
    $bos = array();
    $sorgu = $this->db->prepare($sorgu);
    $sorgu->execute(array($deger));
    $sorgu = $sorgu->fetchAll();
    foreach($sorgu as $deger) {
        $bos[] = $deger;
    }
    return $bos;
}
```

Comment: Append to the array rather than assign it: `$bos[] = $deger;` or array_push($bos, $deger)` Functionally your code is correct, just that you were overwriting `$bos` on each iteration.

Comment: I will point out that you should not need a foreach loop here because you have not manipulated the output from `fetchAll()`. You could just return it directly! `return $sorgu->fetchAll();`

Comment: ty Michael Berkowski . its Done

Comment: Also $yazdirilacak never used. Why use it dostum :)

Comment: @DORE if you do not like the extra objects in your variable use; $sorgu->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Answer (score 0):

Salam,
your code

```
foreach($sorgu as $deger) {
    $bos[] = $deger;
}
```

my answer

```
foreach($sorgu as $deger) {
    array_push($bos,$deger);
}
```

[reference](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_push.asp)